# Displaying values from a different database in openerp

Tags: python, odoo

I have an admin side db and client side db in openerp. I need to show certain fields from admin side db in client side db. I tried using read() but it's not coming up well. Here is the code I used:

```
def read(self, cr, uid, ids, fields=None, context=None, load='_classic_read'):
#Populate local fields with values from external database
    nam=cr.dbname
    #res =  super(sas_clients, self).read(cr, uid, ids, fields=fields, context=context, load=load)                     
    crz = pooler.get_db('con').cursor()
    pool_obj=pooler.get_pool('con').get('sas.accounts')
    srch_db=pool_obj.search(crz,uid,[('db_name','=',nam)],context=context)
    brw_rec=pool_obj.browse(crz,uid,srch_db)
    res =  super(pool_obj, self).read(cr, uid, srch_db[0], fields=fields, context=context, load=load)
    raw_input(res)
    #res = [{'name':brw_rec.name},{'expiry_date':brw_rec.expiry_date},{'curr_no_users':brw_rec.curr_no_users},{'package_id':brw_rec.package_id},{'allowed_users':brw_rec.allowed_users}]
    return res
```

Comment: Don't you want to use `crz` in the last `super().read()` call?

Comment: Nope. Actually, I have worked a solution for this problem. Thanks for your time Andrei..:-)